# wcf unknownmessagereceived with iis host

Tags: wcf

If I have a WCF application hosted on IIS, how can I handle
[`UnknownMessageReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostbase.unknownmessagereceived.aspx) events?

I know how to do it when I build a console host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a service host factory to get access to the service host instance which is used under IIS. You can find more information about service host factories at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx, and the code below shows an example of a factory which listens to the `UnknownMessageReceived` events.

```
public class MyFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        ServiceHost host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        host.UnknownMessageReceived += new EventHandler<UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs>(host_UnknownMessageReceived);
        return host;
    }

    void host_UnknownMessageReceived(object sender, UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something with the message
    }
}
```